# Wrong dashed outline around a <div>

Tags: html, css, border, outline

If you [click here](http://thisisvoid.org/demo/blog), then click on the link "A new article" and then come back to the previous page (browser history previous page), you will see this:

[image]

Why this strange dashed polygonal form/geometry? How to have it rectangular instead?

The code seems normal:

```
<div class="article">
  <a href="article/coolarticle">
    <h2 class="articletitle">A new article</h2>
    <div class="articleinfo">by Jo, on 2015 April 10th</div>
  </a>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't see it. What browser and system are you using?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**

Comment: @liam_ : I use Firefox 36, Windows 7

Comment: @Paulie_D I tried to do that (as we usually do in questions) even in a snippet, but this one it's really difficult, because we need to click on a link and go back to "previous in history", so this is not really possible in a snippet.
By the way, the desired behaviour is written "How to have it rectangular instead"?

Comment: I'm on a Mac OS X using Chrome 46. I'll try on FIrefox.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, happens for me on FF. I'll take a look.

Comment: @Basj Try putting `border: 0 !important` and `outline: 0 !important` in the code. That should get rid of the default selection outline, I think.

Comment: @liam_ Do you have an idea why this strange polygonal form? I'd like to keep the outline, but have it rectangular instead.

Comment: Hmm, no, I'm not sure. I'd suggest you use some CSS to make a custom outline, though, as it's not even displaying on other browsers. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply below style to the a tag should make the outline to be a rectangle:

```
<a href="article/coolarticle" style="display:block;">
```

Comment: Seems to work, but then it also change some others things in the layout. But why has the outline this strange polygonal form ?

Comment: To have better control to such outline, I would suggest you use normalize.css [link](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to reset all CSS from user agent, then you can customise the outline through pseudo class such as :focus, :hover, :active etc.